# Consider the linear transformation $T:R^n\to R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

i really need help understanding this problem for linear algebra, it deals with quite a few concepts that are a large portion of the course I am taking, things that I do not fully understand, it is a 5 part question, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Consider the linear transformation $T:R^n\to R^m$ , defined by $T(v) = Av$, where:

$A= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
        2 & 4 & 3 & 6 \\
        1 & 2 & -1 & -7
        \end{pmatrix}$

and the reduced row echelon form of $A= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 0 & -3 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

a.) Determine the value of m. - I believe this to be 3, because A is the SMR which has 3 rows, please correct me if I am thinking of this incorrectly

b.) Determine the value of n. - I believe this to be 4, because the SMR has 4 columns so you would need a vector with dim(4) in order to satisfy $Av$ right?

c.) Determine a basis for the range $T[R^n]$ of T. - On this I am really uncertain, but my intuition tells me that is is asking for a basis of the resulting transformation which would be a basis for $R^m$, something like {[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]} assuming that i was correct in part (a).

d.) Determine a basis for $kerT$ - I think my unfamiliarity with the concept of the kernel is confusing me. All i really know is that $T(v) = 0$, so i really do not know where to start.

e.) Verify the *rank equation* for $T$. - again i have no idea here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- (a)

The easiest way to determine $m$ is to look at the matrix $A$. It is a $3 \times 4$ matrix which means that it will multiply by a $4 \times 1$ vector to give a $3 \times 1$ vector as the output. Since $m$ references the output we have $m = 3$.

- (b)

From the previous logic we have $n = 4$ since it is referencing the input.

- (c)

You are sort of right about what you said. The only thing is typically we choose the basis from already given vectors. So from the reduced matrix we can see that columns 1 and 3 present us with linearly independent vectors. Now you also have to consider the fact that row operations do not change column vectors and so the basis we want is:

$$\Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \Bigg\}$$

- (d)

To determine the kernel, or null space, we want to solve the system:

$$T(v) = 0$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & -3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ v_4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

which will yield the solution:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 3s - 2t \\ t \\ -4s \\ s \end{pmatrix}$$

where $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$. To form the basis of the kernel, we just want to identify the vector that corresponds to just $t$ and another one for $s$. Then put these two vectors in a set:

$$\Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ -4 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \Bigg\}$$

- (e)

I am going to assume that by rank equation it is referencing the rank-nullity theorem. So we know that the rank of the transformation is given by the dimension of the range giving $rank = 2$. The nullity is defined as the dimension of the kernel giving $nullity = 2$. The rank-nullity theorem states:

$$rank + nullity = n$$

where $n$ is still the same from part (b). Now in our case:

$$2 + 2 = 4$$

the rank-nullity theorem checks out.

Comment: Thank you very much! for the excellent explanation

Answer (score 1):

a), b) you have correct.

c) asks for the *column span* of $A$. Of course, $b_1 = [1, 0, 0]^T$ and $b_2 = [0, 1, 0]^T$ are linearly independent, and the other two columns have $0$ in their third coordinate so they can be written as linear combinations of $b_1, b_2$.

d) Figure out the kernel of $A$. This amounts to solving the linear equations $A(v) = 0$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 0 & -3 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
&x_1\\
&x_2\\
&x_3\\
&x_4\\
\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$
or
$$
x_1 + 2 x_2 -3 x_4 = 0 \\
x_3 + 4 x_4 = 0.
$$

The kernel of $A$ is just the *row span* of the reduced matrix, so a basis is $[1, 2, 0, -3]^T$, $[0, 0, 1, 4]^T$. The kernel therefore has dimension $2$.

e) The rank equation for $T$ is:
$$
\mathrm{dim} \,\mathrm{image}\, T + \mathrm{dim}\,\mathrm{ker}\, T = \mathrm{dim}\, domain(T).
$$
or, in terms of $A$,
$$
\mathrm{rank}\, A + \mathrm{nullity}\, A = \text{number of columns of A}.
$$
As we have seen in c) and d), these quantities on the left hand side are both equal to $2$, and $2+2=4$.

Answer (score 0):

A and b OK.
C) dim(im(T))=2 because the matrix has range 2
D) note that dim(ker(T))=1 (one line of zeros). For example T(2,-1,0,0)=0.